# Не выводится описание категории (cs-cart)

Tags: cs-cart

Подскажите, почему не выводится описание в дочерних категориях? В основной категории man описание выводится без проблем, но вот в дочерних категориях описание не выводится хотя и заполнено в админке. В контроллере описание присутствует, но вот в шаблоне уже его нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте выключением сторонних модулей в Модулях кнопка справа внизу, если описание появится, какой то модуль лажает.